# NOW() BETWEEN date_from AND date_to not working?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a two DATETIME columns: event_start and event_end. I'm not sure why this isn't working.

```
SELECT * FROM ibclc_schedules WHERE NOW() >= event_start AND NOW() <= event_end ORDER BY event_start ASC LIMIT 1
```

I get a "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" printed to the screen.

Comment: Try to run your query in mysql console or some db-client like phpmyadmin to get actual mysql error. If query is ok the problem is the way you connect to db.

Comment: Hm, it says the query was successful. It's just returning an empty result set. I'm trying to get it to return an entry where NOW() falls between the start and end date. I have one in there...

Comment: Check SELECT NOW(); query to get actual mysql server now datetime

Comment: :) I guess not! So my query must be wrong then. I'm looking at the record. The timestamps definitely fall with range. Maybe a server time/timezone mismatch?

Comment: Maybe, I suggest you to debug current datetime of mysql server with query "SELECT NOW();" and check it is really between event_start and event_end of your needed result.

Comment: Ah, that is the problem! EDIT: Yup, just did that :) That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to debug current datetime of mysql server with query `SELECT NOW();` and check it is really between event_start and event_end of your needed result.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a php error kindly check your php code or write your code here so we have an idea about that, or first check this query in phpmyadmin weather its returning something or not